# Valid Business Tax ID

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce3, tax

Is there a way to check on an order if the Business Tax ID was valid? Craft validates this in the order process, but Im in need of being able to narrow down some logic to orders that have a valid value in this field, as opposed to just a populated one. Thanks!

*Not quite what I need:*

```
 foreach ($orders as $order) {
     if($order->billingAddress->businessTaxId){
         ......
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a look in the source code. There's a [`validateBusinessTaxIdAsVatId` config setting](https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/4.x/config-settings.html#validatebusinesstaxidasvatid) that will validate tax IDs on addresses in Commerce. If this option is active, Commerce attaches a behavior ([`ValidateOrganizationTaxIdBehavior`](https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/api/v4/craft-commerce-behaviors-validateorganizationtaxidbehavior.html)) to the `Address` class. The validator uses the [library `ibericode/vat`](https://github.com/ibericode/vat) to validate tax IDs (still on [version 1.x](https://github.com/ibericode/vat/tree/1d24382454481384bbc987dcbc959cfef17d6baa), not the current 2.x branch, note that the public API has changed). You should be able to use the same code to validate tax IDs manually:

```php
use DvK\Vat\Validator;

$validator = new Validator();
$taxId = $order->billingAddress->businessTaxId;
if ($validator->validate($taxId)) {
    // tax ID was valid
}
```

Comment: This works for validating on the spot, but doesn't help if you want to know if the ID was valid at order completion date (which is unfortunately what I need). Sounds like there's no recorded flag or data for it on the order.

Comment: @cherrykoda Can a tax ID be valid at completion but not later? The library that is used by Commerce [only validates the format](https://github.com/ibericode/vat/blob/1d24382454481384bbc987dcbc959cfef17d6baa/src/Validator.php#L19-L48) as far as I can tell, so I don't see how that could change?

Comment: ah ok, I thought the VAT library it hit did more than just format validation. Taxes are weird, people's businesses are weird, it's all weird. lol.

Comment: @cherrykoda I don't think you can get farther than format validation, you would need some kind of backing service to determine whether a tax ID actually exists and corresponds to a real business/person … and do that for every country in which you operate. Not sure if that data is even publicly available in most countries …

Comment: Ive used public VAT ID checking, but you're correct. I wouldn't have been surprised if there was a public lookup API.

Comment: Hey Moritz - as a heads up the validator lib tests format AND if the number exists in VIES. 

I'm unsure if a company goes out of business if the id is removed from VIES (the eu official VAT ID lookup). But felt it's worth mentioning here what the validator does :)

Comment: @cherrykoda Interesting, thanks! So does it perform an API call or is the list embedded in the library? Curious why I didn't find anything about that in the source code ...

Comment: Looks like in https://github.com/ibericode/vat/blob/1.2.1/src/Vies/Client.php there's a defined wsdl file url (so must be SOAP) for the VIES lookup on the ec.europa.eu site (the official EU tool).

Answer (score 1):

The only method I can think of currently is:

```
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        if($order->billingAddress->businessTaxId && $order->totalTax == 0){
         ......
        }
    }
```

Not sure if it's the best way.